# Magento 2 Error while saving product with customizable options when more than 2 options

Tags: magento2, product, custom-options

I am facing below error:

```
Recoverable Error: Object of class Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option could not be converted to string in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 3102
```

While creating product with configurable option, I saved it, but after that when I edit product and resave it, it shows above mentioned error.

> Magento Version: 2.3.1

Please help me..!!

Comment: You create simple product or configurable product?

Comment: simple product. one customizable option is working, but when I create two or more , saving product gives error

Comment: I added 4 custom options. and it's working. If possible then setup new Magento2.3.1

Comment: I can't, in my current magento I am managing 30 stores

Comment: @temper Disable all the custom module and check.

Comment: I already checked and still it's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced this issue before, Please below mentioned commands:

```
composer update
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

This worked for me. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, I will try